# MongoDB Aggregation Framework $Project additional ObjectId reference field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have the following:

```
this.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$tags"},
    {$match: {tags: {$in: pip.activity.tags}}},
    {$group : {_id : '$_id',matches:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project: { _id: 0,matches:1}},
    {$sort: {matches:-1 }},
    callback
);
```

how would I go about including an additional 'external' objectId field in the results? e.g if I have the following:

```
var otherField = new ObjectId('xxxxxxx');
this.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$tags"},
    {$match: {tags: {$in: pip.activity.tags}}},
    {$group : {_id : '$_id',matches:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project: { _id: 0,matches:1,otherField:otherField}}, <-- include otherField
    {$sort: {matches:-1 }},
    callback
);
```

Is this possible or should I be using a forLoop or MapReduce for this particular step? I'm looking for something really efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $project pipeline operator would not let you inject the object, but you can probably insert the object id earlier in the $group operator. If you have a collection:

```
db.foo.save({_id:1,tags:['a','b']})
db.foo.save({_id:2,tags:['b','c']})
db.foo.save({_id:3,tags:['c','d']})
```

You can then write:

```
db.foo.aggregate({
 $unwind: "$tags"},{ 
 $match: { tags: {$in: ['b','c'] } }},{
 $group: { _id: "$_id", matches: {$sum: 1 }, otherField: {$min: new ObjectId()} }},{
 $project: { _id: 0, matches: 1, otherField: 1 }},{
 $sort: { matches: -1 }})
```

The $min or $max can be used here, but it expects an operator or reference to a field so you have to give it one..

Comment: Thanks Nuk Nuk, I gave that a go and it did the job :) Hopefully in a future version there's something that seems less of a workaround, still better than MapReduce!

Comment: The ability to specify arbitrary constant BSON value in a $project seems like a good request - might be worth adding a JIRA for  or vote that up if it already exists. there are some discussions over $literal operator - might be worth following.